# Nomenclature using \nomencl with units far right and reference

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I've been struggling to make nomenclature using the \nomencl package that has units at the far right but also a reference to an equation and or a page.

Here is an MWE with auto-inserted references to equations:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany, final, pdftex]{book}

% Options for Acronyms and Nomenclature
% adapted from here:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166556/how-to-make-a-clean-and-grouped-nomenclature-list
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
  per-mode=symbol
  }

\usepackage[norefeq]{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Acronyms and Abbreviations}]}{%   A - Acronyms
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%                R - Roman
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Calligraphy symbols}]}{%          C - Calligraphy
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Greek symbols}]}{%                G - Greek
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%                 S - Superscripts
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{U}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%                   U - Subscripts
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{%                X - Other Symbols
  {}}}}}}}}}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

% Something I have stumbled upon that uses "Section" numbers but I don't know how to implement
%\newcommand{\mynomencl}[3][section]{%
%  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
%  \unexpanded{\nomenclature{#2}}%
%    {\unexpanded{#3} (\csname the#1\endcsname)}}\x}

\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}%
  }

% To change from ", see equation 1" to only ", see (1)"
\renewcommand{\eqdeclaration}[1]{, see (#1)}
  
% for left aligning the units, comment few upper lines if used
%\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
%  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}\makebox[1cm][l]{#1}}%
%  }

% To change the title (from "Nomenclature" to "Acronyms and Nomenclature")
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Acronyms and Nomenclature}


% As suggested by Barbara
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}

\topskip=40pt
\parskip=10pt
\parindent=0pt
\baselineskip=15pt

\makenomenclature


\begin{document}

\section*{Main equations}
We often use some very neat abbreviations (VNAs) in our text.%
\nomenclature[a]{VNA(s)}{Very Neat Abbreviation(s)}

But then again we want to make a nomenclature in our document as well.

Consider the following equation.
\begin{equation}
\sigma =\frac{N}{A}.
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature[g]{$\sigma$}{normal stress\nomunit{\si{\pascal}}}
\nomenclature[r]{$N$}{axial force\nomunit{\si{\newton}}}
\nomenclature[r]{$A$}{\parbox[t]{.75\textwidth}{area (to explain this simple concept one needs to understand the complicated mathematics behind the integrals... this would take so much space and text to do...)}\nomunit{\si{\meter\squared}}}

Consider also this next equation
\begin{equation}
F_{R}=m a
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature[r]{$F$}{force\nomunit{\si{\newton}}}
\nomenclature[r]{$a$}{acceleration\nomunit{\si{\meter\per\second\squared}}}
\nomenclature[u]{\textsubscript{$R$}}{resultant}%\refeq}

\printnomenclature[1.8cm] % this makes wider column for acronyms/abbreviations to fit better


\end{document}
```

What I get, and an idea of what I've taught of might be a good practice, is shown in the figure below.

[image: First page, just to see the equations for references.]

---

[image]

If I try using `\usepackage[eqref]{nomencl}`, obviously all the entries get a reference. But this is not what I want (e.g I don't want references for all entries, especially not for abbreviations). Please see pink text in image. (Also, for long text - inserted in this way - the position of inserted reference doesn't look that good. It gets inserted at the top of a `\parbox`)

It would be great if I one could create a custom command, such that it can be used only for the items that should be referenced.

I'm also suggesting few options that would be nice:

1. To me, it would make most sense to implement it in a way that it was imagined: at the end of a description as ", see (1)". Please see red text in image.
2. Another suggestion that might look good is right at the start of a description. Please see green text.
3. Or next to units. Before (or perhaps after?). Please see blue text in the image.

Any suggestion to solve the problem, or a suggestion on how to better implement this (i.e symbol, description, using, reference), is welcome.

Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There are a couple of things about your example that aren't "best practices" (although not directly relevant to your question): 1) Don't "break paragraphs" with the double backslash.  Instead, reset `\parindent` to `0pt` and  `\parskip` to `\baselineskip` (there's a package for this, but I've forgotten its name), and 2) Don't leave a blank line before a math display; it fouls up the predefined spacing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have revised it.