# LaTeX not compiling with nomencl package and custom .sty file when inputting another file

Tags: input, nomencl

I am using my university's custom .sty file (cuthesis.sty) to write my thesis. It's been working fine up until now, but when I recently tried to start using the "nomencl" package, it just won't compile. I think I have narrowed it down to the \newchapter command being the issue. If I have \input{chap_filename} in my MWE below, it compiles. If I have \newchapter{chap_filename}, it won't compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the fatal error produced:

> nomenTEST.tex
> 129
> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
> \curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding
> /\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape
> l.129 \newchapter{ch1Introduction}

The console output says:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
> \curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding
> /\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape
> l.129 \newchapter{ch1Introduction}
>
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> Transcript written on nomenTEST.log.
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again

I don't know if I should paste the entire log file into my question - it seems too long to do that. The end of the log file says:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
> \curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding
> /\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape
> l.129 \newchapter{ch1Introduction}
>
> If you really absolutely need more capacity,
> you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
> 17126 strings out of 478582
> 338568 string characters out of 2843400
> 1020820 words of memory out of 3000000
> 35070 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
> 475807 words of font info for 50 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
> 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
> 10000i,22n,19981p,489b,884s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[1committee,phd,nonsequential]{cuthesis}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath} %needed to split equations (and probably other things)
\usepackage[indent,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable} %needed for nomenclature (and other?) tables
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{enumitem} %to create an enumerated list with custom prefixes
\usepackage{gensymb} %I added this package for the degree sign:
\usepackage{tabulary} %I added this package for text wrapping in tables:
\usepackage{float} %I added this package for placing tables in specific locations in the text:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673942/latex-table-positioning
\usepackage{booktabs} %needed for tables that don't have bounding lines on the sides
\usepackage{multirow} %needed for multirow table
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%I added this package to put notes inside tables
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%Added to get "Registered" sign, like copyright
\usepackage{textcomp}


\reffile{../references}

% Defines relative path to folder containing your figures
\graphicspath{{../figures/}}

%I added this package for the nomenclature:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166556/how-to-make-a-clean-and-grouped-nomenclature-list
\usepackage{siunitx}%for writing SI units easily
\sisetup{%
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
  per-mode=symbol
  }
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}{%                A - Acronyms
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%           R - Roman
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%           G - Greek
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%            S - Superscripts
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{U}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%              U - Subscripts
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
    \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{%           X - Other Symbols
  {}}}}}}}}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

%The following makes units right-aligned with the command \nomunit
%\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
%  \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}%
%  }
\makenomenclature

\doublespacing

% Some definitions that could be useful
\newcommand{\Sec}[1]{Sec.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ch}[1]{Chap.~\ref{#1}}
%\newcommand{\App}[1]{\appendixname~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\App}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Fig}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Figure}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Eq}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.g.}

%\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{{\textbf{\underline{[#1]}}}}
\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{{\color{green} [#1]}}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\newchapter{ch1}

$\textrm{CFD}$ and $v$ and $\phi$

\nomenclature[a]{CFD}{Computational Fluid Dynamics}
\nomenclature[r]{$v$}{Fluid velocity\si{\metre\per\second}}
\nomenclature[g]{$\phi$}{Coefficient of viscosity\si{\pascal\second}}


\end{document}
```

The associated file ch1.tex just has some text in it for the MWE. Use this text if you wish and save it as ch1.tex:

```
     each chapter (nonsequential), or if you want the numbers to
     be sequential throughout the whole document.  The default is
     nonsequential for Manuscript format and sequential for
     Standard format.
```

Here is the cuthesis.sty file:

```
\@ifundefined{DeclareOption}{}{% LaTeX2e option
\ProvidesPackage{cuthesis}[2008/08/24 \space  v 1.2]

\DeclareOption{manuscript}{\def\@wantmanuscript{true}}
\DeclareOption{standard}{}

\DeclareOption{phd}{\def\@phddissertation{true}}
\DeclareOption{masters}{}

\DeclareOption{nocopy}{\def\@nolibraryrights{true}}
\DeclareOption{copy}{}

\DeclareOption{noleadpages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}}
\DeclareOption{leadpages}{}

\DeclareOption{norefbib}{\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{refbib}{}

\DeclareOption{noextrapages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{extrapages}{}

\DeclareOption{nonsequential}{\def\@wantnonsequential{true}}
\DeclareOption{sequential}{\def\@wantsequential{true}}

\DeclareOption{4committee}{\def\@fourcommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{5committee}{\def\@fivecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{3committee}{\def\@threecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{2committee}{\def\@twocommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{1committee}{\def\@onecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{6committee}{\def\@sixcommittee{true}}

\ProcessOptions
}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  % standard
  \@ifundefined{@wantnonsequential}{}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}
}{
  % manuscript
  \@ifundefined{@wantsequential}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}{}
}

\def\bibliocite#1{%
  \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{#1}}\fi}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{

\@ifundefined{@extra@b@citeb}{
% this is for use without the cite package
\def\@citex[#1]#2{%
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\hbox{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
}
{
% this is for use with the cite package
\def\@nocite#1{\xdef\@no@sparg{\@ignsp#1 \! }% remove *ALL* spaces
 \if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout {\string\citation {\@no@sparg}}\fi
 \if@filesw \immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@no@sparg}}\fi}
}

}
{

% this section is basically chapterbib

\newenvironment{cbunit}%
{\global\advance\c@inputfile\@ne \xdef\the@ipfilectr{@-\the\c@inputfile}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}}%
{\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}%
  }

\let\cb@include\include
\def\include#1{\clearpage \cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \cb@include{#1}%
\refsforcb%
\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\newcommand\cbinput[1]{\cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \input{#1}\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\@ifundefined{@extra@binfo}{%
  \def\bibcite#1#2{\global\@namedef{b@#1\@extra@binfo}{#2}}%
}{}

\@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}{%
 \def\@citex[#1]#2{%
   \let\@citea\@empty%
   \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do%
     {\@citea\let\@citea\citepunct%
      \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@iden\@citeb}%
      \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibstyle{abbrvnat}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}\fi%
      \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{1}%
      \fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bf ?}%
         \@warning{Citation `\@citeb' in file `\@currentipfile'
             on page \thepage \space undefined}\G@refundefinedtrue}%
      {\hbox{\citeform{\csname b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb\endcsname}}}}}{#1}}
}{}% 2nd arg of \@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}

\def\@iden#1{#1}

\@ifundefined{citeform}{\let\citeform=\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{citepunct}{\def\citepunct{,\penalty\@m\ }}{}

\xdef\@savedjobname{\jobname}% save root file name as a macro
\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname
\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}
\def\@exele@b@citeb{\the@ipfilectr}
\newcount\c@inputfile \global\c@inputfile=0

\gdef\@extra@binfo{}  % in case .aux files are left from old run.

\@ifundefined{reset@font}{\let\reset@font\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{G@refundefinedtrue}{\let\G@refundefinedtrue\relax}{}

\let\cb@bibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\def\cb@roottest{2\ifx\the@ipfilectr\@empty 1\else2\fi}

\def\bibliographystyle#1{\if\cb@roottest\cb@bibliographystyle{#1}\fi}

\def\bibliography#1{\if\cb@roottest%
   \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}\fi%
   \fi \@input{\@currentipfile.bbl}}

\@ifundefined{PackageWarning}{\def\cb@warning{\@warning}}%
 {\def\cb@warning{\PackageWarning{chapterbib}}}

\let\@test@defiii\@testdef

\def\@testdef#1#2#3{%
  \if#1b\relax\@test@defiii b{#2\@extra@binfo}{#3}%
  \else \@test@defiii #1{#2}{#3}\fi%
}

\@ifundefined{bibname}{\def\bibname{Bibliography}}{}

% end of chapterbib section
}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\newcounter{myfigcount}
\newcounter{mytablecount}
\newcounter{myeqncount}
\newcounter{mychapcitecount}
\newcounter{mychaptercount}
\newcounter{myappendixcount}

\def\myusefigurespage{%
  \gdef\@myusefigurespage{true}
}

\def\myusetablespage{%
  \gdef\@myusetablespage{true}
}

\makeatletter

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.20in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.05in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.2in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.25in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}

\brokenpenalty=10000

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} % 1.3 spacing for tables and arrays

\def\myps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
  \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
}

\def\ele@chapapp{}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries  \@chapapp\space \thechapter %this allows the chapter # to be displayed
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\cl@chapter{%
  \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{0}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}%
  }{%
    \@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{footnote}\@elt{section}\@elt{table}%
  }}
\def\thefigure{%
  \addtocounter{myfigcount}{\value{figure}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@figure%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure%
  }}
\def\thetable{%
  \addtocounter{mytablecount}{\value{table}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@table%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@table%
  }}
\def\theequation{%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@equation%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\arabic{equation}%
  }}

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{\def\baselinestretch{1}\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
   \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}\@makefntext
    {\rule{\z@}{\footnotesep}\ignorespaces
      #1\strut}}}

\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{List of References
\@mkboth{}{}}\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin
\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\def\thesisbib{\chapter*{Bibliography
\@mkboth{}{}}\trivlist
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthesisbib=\endtrivlist

\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\pastdegrees#1{\gdef\@pastdegrees{#1}}
\def\degreename#1{\gdef\@degreename{#1}}
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\def\firstcommittee#1{\gdef\@firstcommittee{#1}}
\def\secondcommittee#1{\gdef\@secondcommittee{#1}}
\def\thirdcommittee#1{\gdef\@thirdcommittee{#1}}
\def\fourthcommittee#1{\gdef\@fourthcommittee{#1}}
\def\fifthcommittee#1{\gdef\@fifthcommittee{#1}}
\def\departmentchair#1{\gdef\@departmentchair{#1}}
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} % \author, \title in report
\def\copyrightmonth#1{\gdef\@copyrightmonth{#1}}
\def\@title{}\def\@author{}\def\@dept{Systems and Computer Engineering}
\def\@supervisor{} \def\@firstcommittee{} \def\@secondcommittee{}
\def\@thirdcommittee{} \def\@fourthcommittee{} \def\@fifthcommittee{} \def\@departmentchair{}
\def\@copyrightyear{\number\the\year}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\submitdate{#1}}

\def\@reffile{references}

\def\reffile#1{%
  \def\@reffile{#1}
}

\def\abstract#1{%
  \def\@abstract{#1}
}

\def\acknowledgements#1{%
  \def\@acknowledgements{#1}
}

\def\preface#1{%
  \def\@preface{#1}
}

\def\dedication#1{%
  \def\@dedication{#1}
}

\def\nomenclature#1{%
  \def\@nomenclature{#1}
}


\def\@bibliofileext{bib}
\def\@bibliofile{\jobname\@bibliofileext}

\def\@awork{%
\@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
  thesis
}{
  dissertation
}}

% Print title page
\def\titlep{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\bf\@title}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        by\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
       {\textbf{\@author}\@ifundefined{@pastdegrees}{}{, \textbf{\@pastdegrees}}}\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
%        A \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{thesis}{dissertation} submitted to the\\
        A dissertation submitted to the\\
    Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Affairs\\
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of:\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \bf{\@degreename}\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \begin{center}
        Ottawa, Ontario\\
        \submitdate\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        \copyright Copyright \\
        \@author, \@copyrightyear
    \end{center}\clearpage}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\long\def\signature#1{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{7in}
    \vspace{.4in}
    \hbox{\hfil\shortstack{\vrule width 4in height 0.4pt \\#1}}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\comprof{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
  \begin{flushright}
    \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
      Thesis
    }{
       Dissertation
    }
    Committee\\
    Supervisor
  \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}

% Print signature approval page
\def\signaturepage{%
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\begin{center}
    The undersigned hereby recommends to the\\
    Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Affairs\\
    acceptance of the \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{thesis}{dissertation}\\
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    {\large\bf\@title}
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    submitted by \textbf{\@author}\@ifundefined{@pastdegrees}{}{, \textbf{\@pastdegrees}}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \bf{\@degreename}\\
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \@ifundefined{@twocommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@threecommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fourcommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fivecommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
      & \signature\@fourthcommittee\\
    }
     & \signature{\@departmentchair}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}{
  \@copyrightmonth, \@copyrightyear}
\end{center}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\startingpages{%
  \setcounter{page}{0}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \titlep
  \signaturepage
  \immediate\openout12=\@bibliofile.aux
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibstyle{cubiblio}}
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}
  \@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{
    \doourabstract{\@abstract}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@dedication}{}{
    \doourdedication{\@dedication}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@acknowledgements}{}{
    \doouracknowledgements{\@acknowledgements}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@preface}{}{
    \doourpreface{\@preface}
  }
  \contentspages
  \@ifundefined{@nomenclature}{}{
    \doournomenclature{\@nomenclature}
  }
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
}

\def\doourabstract#1{%
  \sloppy
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\def\doouracknowledgements#1{%
  \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doourdedication#1{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \include{#1}
}

\def\doourpreface#1{%
  \chapter*{Preface}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doournomenclature#1{%
  \chapter*{Nomenclature}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
}

\def\contentspages{\newpage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
      \@ifundefined{@myusetablespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \phantomsection    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
  \@ifundefined{@myusefigurespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \phantomsection    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
}

\def\newchapter#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{mychaptercount}
    \@ifundefined{@noleadpages}{
      \startingpages
    }{}
    \setcounter{mychaptercount}{1}
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \phantomsection
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\ele@chapapp\space \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \phantomsection
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%           This adds ``Chapter N. Chapter Name'' to each non-heading page
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}


\def\newappendix#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
    \setcounter{myappendixcount}{1}
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\startappendix{%
  \def\ele@chapapp{Appendix}
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
     \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    \@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
      \bibliography{\@reffile}
    }{}
    \newpage
  }{}

  \appendix
  % This causes latex to number equations, tables, figures with
  % A-1, A-2, ...
%  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
%  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
%  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
}

% used for manuscript form chapter references
\def\refsforcb{%
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  }{
    \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}
      \relax
    \else
      \newpage
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of References}
%      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
      \bibliography{\@reffile}
      \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
      \newpage
    \fi
  }
}

\def\biblio{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{myfigcount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusefigurespage}\fi
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{mytablecount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusetablespage}\fi
  \fi
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
  \@input{\@bibliofile.bbl}
}

\def\bibliox{\bibliography{\@reffile}}

\@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\biblio
}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\bibliox
}
```

EDIT:
The person who created the custom .sty file helped me solve this. I still don't know what exactly the issue was but I'm going to paste the new .sty file in an answer below in case that helps someone.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks Barbara.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new .sty file that worked and no longer caused conflicts with the nomencl package. Please see the edit in my question above.

```
\@ifundefined{DeclareOption}{}{% LaTeX2e option
\ProvidesPackage{cuthesis}[2008/08/24 \space  v 1.2]

\DeclareOption{manuscript}{\def\@wantmanuscript{true}}
\DeclareOption{standard}{}

\DeclareOption{phd}{\def\@phddissertation{true}}
\DeclareOption{masters}{}

\DeclareOption{nocopy}{\def\@nolibraryrights{true}}
\DeclareOption{copy}{}

\DeclareOption{noleadpages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}}
\DeclareOption{leadpages}{}

\DeclareOption{norefbib}{\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{refbib}{}

\DeclareOption{noextrapages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{extrapages}{}

\DeclareOption{nonsequential}{\def\@wantnonsequential{true}}
\DeclareOption{sequential}{\def\@wantsequential{true}}

\DeclareOption{4committee}{\def\@fourcommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{5committee}{\def\@fivecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{3committee}{\def\@threecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{2committee}{\def\@twocommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{1committee}{\def\@onecommittee{true}}

\ProcessOptions
}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  % standard
  \@ifundefined{@wantnonsequential}{}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}
}{
  % manuscript
  \@ifundefined{@wantsequential}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}{}
}

\def\bibliocite#1{%
  \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{#1}}\fi}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{

\@ifundefined{@extra@b@citeb}{
% this is for use without the cite package
\def\@citex[#1]#2{%
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\hbox{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
}
{
% this is for use with the cite package
\def\@nocite#1{\xdef\@no@sparg{\@ignsp#1 \! }% remove *ALL* spaces
 \if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout {\string\citation {\@no@sparg}}\fi
 \if@filesw \immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@no@sparg}}\fi}
}

}
{

% this section is basically chapterbib

\newenvironment{cbunit}%
{\global\advance\c@inputfile\@ne \xdef\the@ipfilectr{@-\the\c@inputfile}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}}%
{\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}%
  }

\let\cb@include\include
\def\include#1{\clearpage \cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \cb@include{#1}%
\refsforcb%
\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\newcommand\cbinput[1]{\cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \input{#1}\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\@ifundefined{@extra@binfo}{%
  \def\bibcite#1#2{\global\@namedef{b@#1\@extra@binfo}{#2}}%
}{}

\@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}{%
 \def\@citex[#1]#2{%
   \let\@citea\@empty%
   \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do%
     {\@citea\let\@citea\citepunct%
      \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@iden\@citeb}%
      \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibstyle{abbrvnat}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}\fi%
      \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{1}%
      \fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bf ?}%
         \@warning{Citation `\@citeb' in file `\@currentipfile'
             on page \thepage \space undefined}\G@refundefinedtrue}%
      {\hbox{\citeform{\csname b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb\endcsname}}}}}{#1}}
}{}% 2nd arg of \@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}

\def\@iden#1{#1}

\@ifundefined{citeform}{\let\citeform=\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{citepunct}{\def\citepunct{,\penalty\@m\ }}{}

\xdef\@savedjobname{\jobname}% save root file name as a macro
\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname
\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}
\def\@exele@b@citeb{\the@ipfilectr}
\newcount\c@inputfile \global\c@inputfile=0

\gdef\@extra@binfo{}  % in case .aux files are left from old run.

\@ifundefined{reset@font}{\let\reset@font\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{G@refundefinedtrue}{\let\G@refundefinedtrue\relax}{}

\let\cb@bibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\def\cb@roottest{2\ifx\the@ipfilectr\@empty 1\else2\fi}

\def\bibliographystyle#1{\if\cb@roottest\cb@bibliographystyle{#1}\fi}

\def\bibliography#1{\if\cb@roottest%
   \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}\fi%
   \fi \@input{\@currentipfile.bbl}}

\@ifundefined{PackageWarning}{\def\cb@warning{\@warning}}%
 {\def\cb@warning{\PackageWarning{chapterbib}}}

\let\@test@defiii\@testdef

\def\@testdef#1#2#3{%
  \if#1b\relax\@test@defiii b{#2\@extra@binfo}{#3}%
  \else \@test@defiii #1{#2}{#3}\fi%
}

\@ifundefined{bibname}{\def\bibname{Bibliography}}{}

% end of chapterbib section
}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\newcounter{myfigcount}
\newcounter{mytablecount}
\newcounter{myeqncount}
\newcounter{mychapcitecount}
\newcounter{mychaptercount}
\newcounter{myappendixcount}

\def\myusefigurespage{%
  \gdef\@myusefigurespage{true}
}

\def\myusetablespage{%
  \gdef\@myusetablespage{true}
}


\makeatletter

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.20in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.05in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.2in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.25in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.8in}
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}

\brokenpenalty=10000

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} % 1.3 spacing for tables and arrays

\def\myps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
  \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
}

\def\ele@chapapp{}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter %this allows the chapter # to be displayed
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\cl@chapter{%
  \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{0}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}%
  }{%
    \@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{footnote}\@elt{section}\@elt{table}%
  }}
\def\thefigure{%
  \addtocounter{myfigcount}{\value{figure}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@figure%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure%
  }}
\def\thetable{%
  \addtocounter{mytablecount}{\value{table}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@table%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@table%
  }}
\def\theequation{%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@equation%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\arabic{equation}%
  }}

% This xfloat definition was apparently originally created to allow single spacing
% within floats such as figures and tables.  Also, this was originally written for
% LaTeX2.09 and not updated for LaTeX2e.  Hence, with the setspace package now
% available, I'm commenting this definition out since there are known conflicts
% with this and using the color package.
%\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
%   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
%      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
%    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
%       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
%       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
%                        {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
%                         \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
%                         \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
%                         \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
%         }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
%    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
%    \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
%    \boxmaxdepth\z@
%    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{\def\baselinestretch{1}\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
   \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}\@makefntext
    {\rule{\z@}{\footnotesep}\ignorespaces
      #1\strut}}}

\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{List of References
\@mkboth{}{}}\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin
\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\def\thesisbib{\chapter*{Bibliography
\@mkboth{}{}}\trivlist
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthesisbib=\endtrivlist

\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\pastdegrees#1{\gdef\@pastdegrees{#1}}
\def\degreename#1{\gdef\@degreename{#1}}
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\def\firstcommittee#1{\gdef\@firstcommittee{#1}}
\def\secondcommittee#1{\gdef\@secondcommittee{#1}}
\def\thirdcommittee#1{\gdef\@thirdcommittee{#1}}
\def\fourthcommittee#1{\gdef\@fourthcommittee{#1}}
\def\departmentchair#1{\gdef\@departmentchair{#1}}
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} % \author, \title in report
\def\copyrightmonth#1{\gdef\@copyrightmonth{#1}}
\def\@title{}\def\@author{}\def\@dept{Systems and Computer Engineering}
\def\@supervisor{} \def\@firstcommittee{} \def\@secondcommittee{}
\def\@thirdcommittee{} \def\@fourthcommittee{} \def\@departmentchair{}
\def\@copyrightyear{\number\the\year}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\submitdate{#1}}

\def\@reffile{references}

\def\reffile#1{%
  \def\@reffile{#1}
}

\def\abstract#1{%
  \def\@abstract{#1}
}

\def\acknowledgements#1{%
  \def\@acknowledgements{#1}
}

\def\preface#1{%
  \def\@preface{#1}
}

\def\dedication#1{%
  \def\@dedication{#1}
}

\def\nomenclatureOld#1{%
  \def\@nomenclatureOld{#1}
}


\def\@bibliofileext{bib}
\def\@bibliofile{\jobname\@bibliofileext}

\def\@awork{%
\@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
  thesis
}{
  dissertation
}}

% Print title page
\def\titlep{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\bf\@title}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        by\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        {\textbf{\@author}\@ifundefined{@pastdegrees}{}{, \textbf{\@pastdegrees}}}\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        A \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{thesis}{dissertation} submitted to the\\% A dissertation submitted to the\\    
        Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Affairs\\
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \bf{\@degreename}\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \begin{center}
        Ottawa, Ontario\\
        \submitdate\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        \copyright Copyright \\
        \@author, \@copyrightyear
    \end{center}\clearpage}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\long\def\signature#1{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{7in}
    \vspace{.4in}
    \hbox{\hfil\shortstack{\vrule width 4in height 0.4pt \\#1}}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\comprof{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
  \begin{flushright}
    \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
      Thesis
    }{
       Dissertation
    }
    Committee\\
    Supervisor
  \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}

% Print signature approval page
\def\signaturepage{%
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\begin{onepointfivespacing}
\begin{center}
    The undersigned hereby recommends to the\\
    Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Affairs\\
    acceptance of the \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{thesis}{dissertation}\\
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    {\large\bf\@title}
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    submitted by \textbf{\@author}\@ifundefined{@pastdegrees}{}{, \textbf{\@pastdegrees}}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \bf{\@degreename}\\
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \@ifundefined{@twocommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@threecom mittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fourcommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fivecommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
      & \signature\@fourthcommittee\\
    }
     & \signature{\@departmentchair}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}{
  \@copyrightmonth, \@copyrightyear}
\end{center}
\end{onepointfivespacing}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\startingpages{%
  \setcounter{page}{0}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \titlep
  \signaturepage
  \immediate\openout12=\@bibliofile.aux
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibstyle{cubiblio}}
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}
  \@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{
    \doourabstract{\@abstract}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@dedication}{}{
    \doourdedication{\@dedication}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@acknowledgements}{}{
    \doouracknowledgements{\@acknowledgements}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@preface}{}{
    \doourpreface{\@preface}
  }
  \contentspages
  \@ifundefined{@nomenclatureOld}{}{
    \doournomenclature{\@nomenclatureOld}
  }
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
}

\def\doourabstract#1{%
  \sloppy
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\def\doouracknowledgements#1{%
  \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doourdedication#1{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \include{#1}
}

\def\doourpreface#1{%
  \chapter*{Preface}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doournomenclature#1{%
%  \chapter*{Nomenclature}
%  \phantomsection  
%  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
}

\def\contentspages{\newpage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
      \@ifundefined{@myusetablespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \phantomsection    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
  \@ifundefined{@myusefigurespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \phantomsection    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
}

\def\newchapter#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{mychaptercount}
    \@ifundefined{@noleadpages}{
      \startingpages
    }{}
    \setcounter{mychaptercount}{1}
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \phantomsection
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\ele@chapapp\space \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \phantomsection
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%           This adds ``Chapter N. Chapter Name'' to each non-heading page
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}


\def\newappendix#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
    \setcounter{myappendixcount}{1}
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\startappendix{%
  \def\ele@chapapp{Appendix}
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
%     \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
      \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    \@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
      \bibliography{\@reffile}
    }{}
    \newpage
  }{}

  \appendix
  % This causes latex to number equations, tables, figures with
  % A-1, A-2, ...
%  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
%  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
%  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
}

% used for manuscript form chapter references
\def\refsforcb{%
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  }{
%    \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}
%      \relax
%    \else
      \newpage
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of References}
%      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
%      \bibliography{\@reffile}
%      \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
%      \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}      
     \newpage
%    \fi
  }
}

\def\biblio{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{myfigcount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusefigurespage}\fi
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{mytablecount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusetablespage}\fi
  \fi
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
  \@input{\@bibliofile.bbl}
}

\def\bibliox{\bibliography{\@reffile}}

\@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\biblio
}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\bibliox
}
```